# How to align two divs horizontally and force the contents to be inside the divs

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, alignment

I'm sure that something similar has already answered but I could not find the excact scenario that I'm dealing with right now so, here is my problem: I've a  div in the right (with a fixed width) and all the left side is from another div. Ok, I can put both divs properly but my problem is that second one contents are displayed below the first div. I've tried several configurations with no success. I know that is a silly question but I would really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>      
</head>

<body>

<div>   
    <div style="display: inline-block; width:100%; display: inline-block;"> 
        <div id="sidemenu" style="background-color: #004E87; position: fixed; width: 100px; height: 100%; float:left; display: inline-block;">
        </div>
        <div id="leftside" style="width: 100%; float:right; background-color: yellow; display: inline-block;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Updated using flex!

My problem now is that I cannot get the 100 height of the screen.. Ay help?

```
<div class="flex-container" style="display: flex; width: 100%; background-color: green; align-items: stretch;">
    <div class="flex-item" style="background-color: yellow; width: 100px; height: 100%;">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item" style="background-color: red; width: 100px;">2</div>
</div>
```

I would really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Consider to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead a floating div. N.B in bootstrap 4 docs you will find a weel explained examples.

Comment: I've updated my question using flex but I'm still not able to do it :( My problem now is covering the full height... I've tried to use the stretch property with no success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>      
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2" style="background-color: #004E87;height:100vh">      
        </div>
        <div class="col" >
          <div class="row" style="background-color: yellow">
            <div class = "col">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            <div>
          <div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
   
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please see if this works for you. as you are using bootstrap you can divide a row into two columns 2 and 10 each to get the result you want. Let me know if you need any other help. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly I have the same issue with this. I can distribute the space as I want with flex (or using your method) but in both cases, the DIVs only use the space needed and not the 100% of the screen height.

Comment: @Ivan do you want the left side to be full screen width or both the column to be of fulll screen

Comment: I want that left side will be 100px witdh and 100% height (like a side menu!) and the rest of the screen will be the second column (and its contents will be displayed only in this space, not below the left column).

Comment: i have done the changes for the same please see if it works for u now :)

Comment: Almost! But thanks to your last change I achieve it:) I've just added a "width: 100px" to force this width in the first column and that's it. Thank you s much!

Comment: happy to help :)